# Google SilentSignIn C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, google-signin

I'm trying to implement Google Sign In in a app that I'm testing out. I can make everything connect and work without any problems however I want the app to attempt to silently log in (cached credentials) and move on if it finds them.

The only examples I can find to do this are in Java and while it's not radically different from C# I'm not really an expert in that either :)

I have taken the example from here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java

However I have hit what I think is a catch 22 that I would like some help with. If I use the code:

```
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.SilentSignIn(plusClient);
    if(opr != null)
    {
        if (opr.IsDone)
        {
            Console.Out.Write("we have cached login");
            try
            {
                GoogleSignInResult signInResult = opr.Get;
                GoogleSignInAccount gsa = signInResult.SignInAccount;

                Toast.MakeText(this, gsa.DisplayName, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.Write("error getting cache login: {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Out.Write("we're gonna have to log in");
        }
```

Then the first line fails on the OptionalPendingResult section for:

> CS0308    The non-generic type 'OptionalPendingResult' cannot be used
>   with type arguments

I can drop the  and the error goes away. I can then use opr.isDone so I know this is working correctly. However I then get an error on the line:

```
                GoogleSignInResult signInResult = opr.Get;
```

> CS0428    Cannot convert method group 'Get' to non-delegate type
>   'GoogleSignInResult'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

or, if I put brackets at the end I get

```
                GoogleSignInResult signInResult = opr.Get();
```

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'Java.Lang.Object' to
>   'Android.Gms.Auth.Api.SignIn.GoogleSignInResult'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Now, I'm pretty sure the original cast that I removed is at the heart of the problem however I don't know enough about this and Google just returns java results.

Anyone able to help out?

Thanks,
Justin

Answer (score 1):

when the error says

> An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

it's telling you need to explicitly cast (change the type) of the object, like this:

```
GoogleSignInResult signInResult = (GoogleSignInResult) opr.Get();
```

Comment: That worked, I knew I was missing something basic! Cheers.